# Not getting the Mounted host File's Content inside the container when using kubernetes hostPath

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to mount a file to a container using Kubernetes hostPath.
This is the syntax.

```
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /file.txt
      name: myfile
  
  volumes:
  - name: myfile
    hostPath:
      path: /file.txt
```

Once I deployed , I can see file.txt inside the container under /file.txt.
But the contents are missed. The file size is 0 inside the container.
Any idea why the contents of the file in host are not reflecting inside the container. ???

Comment: How are you running your k8s cluster? Standalone? minikube? sth else? Dis you put the file in a correct path on a k8s host machine?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this:

```
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /file.txt
      name: myfile
```

is telling k8s to mount the contents of `file.txt` to a directory. You're not explictly providing a `subPath` argument to inform k8s this is a file and not a folder.

See here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

I think what you're actually wanting to do is:

```
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /file.txt
    name: myfile
    subPath: file.txt
  
  volumes:
  - name: myfile
    hostPath:
      path: /
```

I'd also recommend avoiding using `/` as a hostPath. Put it in a sub-folder. It'll probably make things a little easier to follow that way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Apart form this change , i have added node selector to select the node in which i had the file.

Comment: @Balaganesh.V Yes, I didn't mention but also making sure the container is scheduled to the node is important. Please mark my answer if you think it gives you the information you need.